# Why this doesn't crash?

Tags: ios, objective-c, crash, exc-bad-access

Why the second line in the loop (the a.retainCount one) won't crash (due to bad access) ?

```
NSArray* a0 = @[[NSMutableString stringWithString:@"a"]];    
NSArray * arr = [NSArray arrayWithObject:a0];
[a0 release];[a0 release];

for (NSArray* a in arr)
{
    //NSLog(@"%d", (a == a0) );
    NSLog(@"RC: %d", a.retainCount);
}
```

but it would crash if the first line in loop (a == a0 one) is un-commented.

This would definitely crash when the autorelease pool is drained, but I am specifically asking about the second line in loop, not afterwards.

Can anyone please explain?

Comment: Can you explain what this has to do with `xcode`?

Comment: Is this a homework question? We aren't here to do your homework.

Comment: Why do you release the `a0` object when you do not own it? There is no `alloc`, `new` or `copy` thus you are over releasing it. This might be why it crashes when you do the equals log, because it is pointing to an invalid memory address.

Comment: `(a == a0)` probably crashes as `sizeof(BOOL) != sizeof(int)`; `int` being what the `%d` format specifier is expecting.

Comment: actually i thought this was a dumb question at first, but the more that I am looking at it, it may not be.

Comment: @trojanfoe: I *think* that comparison operators evaluate to an `int`. And even if not: in a variable argument list all integer arguments "smaller" than `int` are promoted to `int`.

Comment: @MartinR Yeah I think you might be right.

Comment: it will crash if you put it in an autorelease pool and drain it... the autoreleased object ends up leaking this way.

Comment: Probably this is just an "experiment" to study how memory management works.

Comment: Even if an object is deallocated, the memory that it used might still be valid until it is used for something else. The first NSLog() just causes the memory to be reused.

Comment: @Popeye: I just added xcode, because this happened in xcode :)

Comment: This is not a homework question. I discovered it while exploring a crash.

Comment: @GradyPlayer: I agree it will crash when it reaches the [pool release] statement. But I am specifically asking about the second line in loop.

Comment: @MartinR: I don't think that first NSLog causes the memory to be reused. It just compares pointers (addresses), same as 4 byte integer comparison.

Comment: @Sohaib: But NSLog() is a function call that uses NSString internally to format messages, so that may well cause any unused memory to be reused and overwritten.

Comment: @MartinR: Even if NSLog overwrites the memory, why without NSLog it shows retainCount 1 ? Shouldn't it show 0 ? Also, shouldn't accessing the released memory cause bad_access (even if objects contents are intact, it just doesn't belong to us) ? Its basics of memory management ?

Comment: There is no guarantee that an over-released object will cause a crash at any particular time.  Generally (when you don't have certain debugging options enabled) you don't get a crash until the space belonging to the object is reallocated to a new use.  There's nothing to cause that until you hit the first NSLog, which creates a mutable string object to receive the formatted log value.  Then the next reference to the object (in the next NSLog) goes gablooie.  Note that in the general case the reallocation could occur in a different thread.

Comment: @GradyPlayer It's not a dumb question, it's a question which shows no research effort. -1.

Comment: @Sohaib A quick Google search for "Objective-C autorelease release not crash" brought up the dupe link **as the very first hit,** don't tell me you did research before posting, because you clearly didn't.

Comment: @H2CO3 the autorelease isn't where it was throwing them, the thing that was throwing them was that by not calling NSLog it wasn't mashing the memory and not crashing...

Comment: @GradyPlayer those convenience methods all return autoreleased objects, so this **is** a dupe.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please review http://www.whentouseretaincount.com/

Sending a message to a deallocated object is **undefined behavior**.   It may crash, it may not.

In this case, it isn't crashing because the memory that contained the object hasn't been overwritten by something else.   If you were to turn on Malloc Scribble, it'd crash.  That call to `NSLog()` *coincidentally* causes the memory to be scribbled upon, causing the crash.

`retainCount` can never return 0 exactly because messaging a deallocated object is undefined behavior.   The system doesn't bother decrementing the RC to 0 because the object is no longer viable anyway.

I'm curious within what context this question came up?   Are you using a tutorial or class materials that use `retainCount`?

---

It isn't always a segmentation fault for the same reason the runtime doesn't decrement the retain count to 0;  efficiency.

To make it a guaranteed segmentation fault would mean wasting a few cycles writing bogus values to the memory (or decrementing the retain count).

As it is, `free()` just marks the memory as being available for future `malloc()`s.  It doesn't modify the contents of the memory in any way, hence the *undefined behavior*.

Comment: +1, I am so glad somebody made that website... but I think the OP probably started messing with the retain count while isolating the bug (giving them the benefit of the doubt.)

Comment: Oh, sure -- everyone goes down the RC path at least a couple of times when they are new to the environment (and sometimes when they are not so new).   Nothing wrong with that and understanding why it is so useless provides a lot of tangential information that is universally applicable to other aspects of iOS/Cocoa development.

Comment: @bbum: printing retain count was not the real thing I was interested in. The real interest was why it didn't crash. Perhaps because I had the theory that as soon as an object's retain count reaches 0, its memory is sent back to system and after that calling its method *should* crash (specially in case the called method uses some instance variable).

Comment: @bbum: Why sending a message to deallocated instance is undefined behaviour ?

Comment: @Sohaib: It's undefined behavior because accessing deallocated memory is undefined behavior according to the C spec, and every message send has to access at least the first word at the receiver's address.

Comment: I meant why isn't it always segmentation fault ?

Comment: @Sohaib Because, on `free()`, the memory isn't modified in any way.

Comment: @bbum: I am asking why sending message to deallocated instance is not always segmentation fault ?

Comment: @Sohaib that question has been answered several times now;  when an object is deallocated, `free()` is called on the pointer.  The memory is not modified, just marked for reuse.

Comment: I thought that MMU should make the app crash (via OS of course) as something is accessed outside the memory available to an app. But it looks that the memory remains under app's ownership even after its released.

Comment: @Sohaib on `free()` (or `dealloc`) the memory is given back to the app's heap for use by that app.  It is not given back to the system *unless* there are enough contiguous free memory that an entire page of memory is unused *and* the system is under memory pressure to the point that the system reclaims the memory.  Even then, single pages are unlikely to be recovered by the system because VM map fragmentation is expensive and generally avoided.

Answer (score 3):

This could crash any time. Likely the first line in the loop triggered the memory at the dangling pointer "a" allocated for other use. So when "a" is referenced on the second line, anything could happen.
If you turn on the XCode options in "Scheme -> Diagnostics -> Memory Management", this may crash immediately.

Comment: Yes. Actually *any* NSLog call instead of `DLog(@"%d", (a == a0) )` causes the next statement to crash.

Comment: I just replaced the DLog with NSLog and verified. The effect is same.

Comment: @Joe Smith: Which options exactly you mean ?

Comment: @Sohaib: What I meant is: Even `NSLog(@"%d", 42)` causes a crash in the next line. The NSLog call causes the memory of the deallocated instance to be overwritten.

Comment: The behaviour is consistent. It "should" crash every time whether or not first line is commented. But "doesn't" crash when first line is commented.

Comment: @MartinR: Nice observation, I didn't check that. Even if NSLog overwrites the memory, why without NSLog it shows retainCount 1 ? Shouldn't it show 0 ?
Also shouldn't accessing the released memory cause bad_access (even if objects contents are intact, it just doesn't belong to us) ? Its basics of memory management ?

Comment: where is `a` dereferenced? `a==a0` doesn't deference it

Comment: @Sohaib: There is no object with retainCount 0. If an object with retainCount 1 is released then the object is deallocated, probably using `free()` or something similar. That just means that the memory previously occupied by the object is now available again for future allocations. But unless the memory page is given back to the system, the memory still exists and can be accessed.

Comment: @MartinR: What retainCount it would show after we have released an object (having retainCount of 1 before releasing) and before the page (in which the object resided) is returned back to system ?

Comment: @Sohaib retain counts never get to 0 internally if they would go to 0 they get sent the dealloc instead... there is no way to read a 0 from a retain count...

Comment: @MartinR you should post an answer, as you are correct, I have verified.

Comment: @Sohaib: Messaging an object after it's been dealloc'd is undefined behavior, so there is no value an object "should" return when you message it after it's been deallocated. It's a bit like asking "What should a symphony smell like?" You can't smell a symphony, and you can't message a deallocated object. Trying to do either will have unpredictable results.